# Bringing an Apple Airpod from Finland to Poland via flight

Tags: customs-and-immigration, poland, finland, gifts

I am planning to bring an airpod that I bought in Finland to Poland for a friend as a gift. I have the bill and also the packaging is still intact. My question is Do I need to declare or pay any customs at the Poland Airport? I tried to find this exact info, but unfortunately couldn't find any.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, since Finland and Poland are both in the EU single market / customs union and there are no customs duties between members.

You can use the blue channel on arriving in Poland, signifying to customs that you arrived from a EU country, as opposed to green/red when arriving from outside the customs union.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you link me to an official document which states this.

Comment: e.g. here https://eur-lex.europa.eu/summary/chapter/12.html

Comment: Also regarding blue channels here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customs#Blue_channel

Comment: Awesome. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 5):

In general, you don't declare items on the customs, even if you travel from outside the EU, provided that

- the import is occasional in nature and non-commercial (you don't intend to sell the items)
- the items are not restricted or banned for imports (artwork of historical value, drugs, guns, etc.)
- the total value of your imported items is within the allowance (which is 430 euro per traveler for [Poland](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/pl-Poland-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm))

Comment: Just to clarify, it’s the **total** value of the items which counts, not the value of each.

Comment: @jcaron Exactly. I already said "items", not "item", but I'll add "total" to clarify.

Comment: This is correct but very confusing as an answer to a question about travel between Finland and Poland. Even if another answer already covers it, you should also address intra-EU travel and do a better job of distinguishing the two. Incidentally, €430 has nothing at all to do with Poland, it's an EU-wide threshold and only applies when flying (not by land).